# Not updating value and showing the same thing again when update button is pressed

Tags: php, sqlite

This is an update query for a simple crud im a beginner and it doesnt seem to work.I have tried multiple ways but it just doesnt work the $value seems to be null and it redirects towrds the unsuccessful page

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_GET['updte']))
{
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $email=$_GET['email'];
    $password=$_GET['pass'];
    $sql2="UPDATE `users` SET `name` = '$name', `email` = '$email', `password` = '$password' WHERE `users`.`id` =$id";
    $val=$db->query($sql2);
    if ($val){
        header('Location:show.php');
    }
    else{
        header('Location:nsuccess.php');
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<?php include 'db.php';
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="select * from users where id='$id'";
$rows=$db->query($sql);
$row=$rows->fetch_assoc();
?>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>List</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 70px;">
        <h1 class="text-center">All Users List</h1>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <table class="table">
                <hr><br>
                <form method="get" action="up.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h1><?php echo $row['id'];?></h1>
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" required name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" class="form-control">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" required name="email" value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>" class="form-control">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" required name="pass" value="<?php echo $row['password'];?>" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="updte" value="Update" class="btn btn-success">&nbsp;
                </form>
            </table>
            <button onclick="history.go(-1);" class="btn btn-primary">Back </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just want the values to be updated

Comment: do NOT store the user's password as plain text in the db.. just don't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you have @password in your update statement instead of $password.
DB might be looking for it's own variable that's not been set

Comment: You don't pass id from your html form. You need something like <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $row['id'];?>'> in the form as well

Answer (score 1):

First and very important: You are wide open for SQL injections.

Then any user can override any user settings by providing a combination of id, name, mail and password simply by editing the URL.

You used `@password` instead of `$password`.